# My UICollectionViewCell item is nil?

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionviewcell, iboutlet

My CollectionViewCell imageView is nil

**My Cell File is here**

```
class MyTicketsCollectionViewCell: UICollectionViewCell {

     @IBOutlet weak var imgTicket: UIImageView!
}
```

**My Controller File Code is here**

```
class MyTicketsCollectionViewController: UICollectionViewController {

     var photos: [String] = ["ticket1","ticket2","ticket3","ticket4"]

     override func viewDidLoad() {
     super.viewDidLoad()

         self.collectionView?.register(MyTicketsCollectionViewCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "MyTicketsCollectionViewCell")

     }

     override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

         return photos.count
     }

     override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {


         let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "MyTicketsCollectionViewCell", for: indexPath) as! MyTicketsCollectionViewCell

         cell.imgTicket.image = UIImage(named: photos[indexPath.row])

        return cell
    }

}
```

Error is "Thread 1: Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value"

> When I debug it then
>
> ```
>  cell.imgTicket is nil
> ```

How solve this issue?

Comment: Where is the "visual" of your cell? In a separate xib? Inside the CollectionView in your stroyboard?

Comment: Your outlet is not properly connect. recheck it.

Comment: Type mismatch: `ActiveTicketsCollectionViewCell` != `MyTicketsCollectionViewCell`

Answer (score 1):

Try changing your code to

```
   override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

     let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "MyTicketsCollectionViewCell", for: indexPath) as! MyTicketsCollectionViewCell

     cell.imgTicket.image = UIImage(named: photos[indexPath.row])

    return cell
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are dequeuing `ActiveTicketsCollectionViewCell` but the cell is registered under `MyTicketsCollectionViewCell`.

Answer (score 0):

There is 2 possible solutions here...

**1.** Might be **ActiveTicketsCollectionViewCell** have not the property **imgTicket** or you mention a wrong cell class here as u have mentioned a different cell class name **MyTicketsCollectionViewCell** so try to write this code.

```
  let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "MyTicketsCollectionViewCell", for: indexPath) as! MyTicketsCollectionViewCell

  cell.imgTicket.image = UIImage(named: photos[indexPath.row])

  return cell
```

**2.** Might be you have missed to connect your property (`@IBOutlet weak var imgTicket: UIImageView!`) with the Outlet (xib or storyboard).